# Support Fragment Manager .replace() and ViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

It appears that whenever you use the `.replace()` method within a transaction with the Support Fragment Manager the ViewModel is recreated. Is this intentional? The Fragment instance itself is not changing and the ViewModel will be (partially) preserved during rotation/configuration changes.

I'm seeing the following scenarios:

1. Get View model ref (count = 0), update count = 1, rotate, count = 1, onCreate called *again* and count = 0 (view model recreated).
2. Call `.replace()` and view model is recreated (activity and fragment instances unchanged).

Using support library 26.0.0.

The `ViewModel` is being created in `onCreate` of my fragment and is scoped to the `Fragment`:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
```

Anyone shed some light on if this is normal?

Comment: "The Fragment instance itself is not changing" -- what do you mean by this? A `ViewModel` is implemented as a child retained fragment of whatever `FragmentActivity` or `Fragment` you pass into `ViewModelProviders.of()`.

Comment: In the activity I have a fragment array and I'm just swapping between the fragments in the array (using a bottom nav):

`fragments = mapOf(id to fragment, etc)`

Then later: 

`supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit()`

I can see that the fragment references are the same (not being recreated).

Comment: If i move to activity scope it works fine btw. `viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)`

Comment: So, just to be clear: you created a fragment, added it via a `FragmentTransaction`, ran another transaction that replaced it, ran *another* `replace()` transaction that put it back... and then you lost your `ViewModel`? Perhaps when a fragment is managed again by a `FragmentManager`, its nested `FragmentManager` gets replaced. I avoid nested fragments like the plague, so I don't know the rules for child fragments of a fragment, and the `ViewModel` is backed by a retained child fragment of your fragment.

Comment: Correct to all of the above.

Comment: If you can create a reproducible test case, consider [filing an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448). At minimum, this should be documented.

Answer (score 3):

As @CommonsWare mentioned, the `viewmodel` instance inside `fragment` should be the same in `Activity`.

Therefore, inside the Activity , you should do something like this

`MyViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);`

Inside the Fragment , you should do something like this

`MyViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);`

In result, they will use the same instance.

**However, if you try to use it inside the fragment**

`MyViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);`

The Viewmodel will be recreated in the fragment when you rotate the device. **Since the instance is preserved inside the fragment not the activity, when the activity recreated, the fragment will also be recreated, and the MyViewModel instance.**

Try to take a look on the example on master detail fragment (which might be easy to resolve your problem) [ViewModel in Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html)

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}

public class DetailFragment extends LifecycleFragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getSelected().observe(this, { item ->
           // update UI
        });
    }
}
```

I have also made the simple Master Detail template on the github

[SimpleDetailActivity.java](https://github.com/charlesng/SampleAppArch/blob/master/communitcation-fragments/src/main/java/com/example/communitcation_fragments/ui/masterdetail/SimpleDetailActivity.java)

[SimpleDetailFragment.java](https://github.com/charlesng/SampleAppArch/blob/master/communitcation-fragments/src/main/java/com/example/communitcation_fragments/ui/masterdetail/SimpleDetailFragment.java)

Comment: I don't think this is what the Android guys intended when they designed the API. If passing `this` (the fragment) as the `ViewModel` store is not what they want they can easily deny that by forcing an `Activity`. Obviously passing the `Fragment` is the right solution when you want the `ViewModel` to be tied to the `Fragment`. To address the post on why a new instance is being created is a different topic for this comment

Answer (score 2):

`replace()` is suppossed to be called when you make different fragment. For the same fragment you call `update()`.

`replace()` method means you can replace your current Fragment with something different fragment, which has something different layout (physical structure). You can't even guarantee that it starts from the same memory that the previous fragment used. `ViewModel` is kind of layout for whole container. So, for the object with different physical structure and (possibly with different memory -- I am writing **possibly** because you can replace with the same fragment also), you have to recreate different `ViewModel` to **define it's container**. This is because one `ViewModel` object points one reference Container, next time you have different fragment, your fragment container is defined by ViewModel is somewhere else, so you need another `ViewModel` object to point that Fragment Container.

But when you do `update()`, or `rotate()`, you guarantee the updated fragment's memory space can decrease/increase but still it's starting memory remains same. So no need to create the `ViewModel`. This is because your old `ViewModel` object is referencing the same old Fragment's container.

When you do create(), it creates GUI everything, so, obviously, there happen `ViewModel` creation again.

The tracking of `ViewModel` `count` is based on the above explanation.

The ViewModel is being created in onCreate of my fragment and is scoped to the Fragment. This is kind of power delegation to the fragment.